# problem installing torch on conda environment

Tags: pycharm, conda, torch

Hi I'm trying to install torch on conda environment on pycharm, but I get this error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.


PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - torch

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Can anyone please help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While the Python *module* is named `torch`, the Conda package is named `pytorch`. Typically, users follow [the official recommendations](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) and create a dedicated environment. For example,

```bash
conda create -n pytorch -c pytorch -c conda-forge python=3.9 pytorch torchvision torchaudio
```

Include all packages you plan to use at creation time (example, include `cudatoolkit` or `cpuonly`).